# List Filter Custom Adapter dont give result

Tags: android

I m developing app where there is list and above edit text,the moment i will type something in editText i should get the result matching for the typed word.bt i cant get the result,Plz tell where am i making mistake ? Below are my Activity and Adapter.

**Activity****

```
public class ListFilterActivity extends ListActivity{

    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_filter);   

        list = getListView();
        list.isTextFilterEnabled();

//      final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
//                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
//                getModel());
        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(ListFilterActivity.this, getModel());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);
        filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getModel() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Linux");
        list.add("Windows7");
        list.add("Suse");
        list.add("Eclipse");
        list.add("Ubuntu");
        list.add("Solaris");
        list.add("Android");
        list.add("Ayes");
        list.add("iPhone");
        return list;
    }



}
```

***Adapter******

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;
        private final ArrayList<String> names;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private TextView txt;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names) {
            super(context, R.layout.row, names);
            this.context = context;
            this.names = names;
            mInflater =  LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

public Filter getFilter() {     
        if(newFilter == null) {
            newFilter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("TAG", "publishResults");
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {             

                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<String> i = new ArrayList<String>();

                    if (prefix!= null && prefix.toString().length() > 0) {

                        for (int index = 0; index < names.size(); index++) {
                            String si = names.get(index);
                            if(si.compareTo(prefix.toString()) == 0){
                                i.add(si);  
                            }
                        }
                        results.values = i;
                        results.count = i.size();                   
                    }
                    else{
                        synchronized (names){
                            results.values = names;
                            results.count = names.size();
                        }
                    }

                    return results;
                }

            };
        }
            //    Log.d("TAG", "end getFilter");
        return newFilter;
    }
@Override
    public String getItem(int position) {    
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {    
        return super.getCount();
    }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View rowView  = convertView;
            if(rowView == null) {       
                rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                txt = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            }
            else {
                rowView.getTag();
            }
            txt.setText(names.get(position));

            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

plz help me out....

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to implement `Filterable` to your Adapter Class and Override `getFilter()`

Checkout [this](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/app/LauncherActivity.java.shtml) complete example for Filtering custom Adapter.

**UPDATE:**

```
      public class ListFilterActivity extends ListActivity {

                private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> mOriginalValues;

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, getModel());
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    EditText filterEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterText);

                    // Add Text Change Listener to EditText
                    filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
                            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        }
                    });
                }

                private List<String> getModel() {
                    list.add("Linux");
                    list.add("Windows7");
                    list.add("Suse");
                    list.add("Eclipse");
                    list.add("Ubuntu");
                    list.add("Solaris");
                    list.add("Android");
                    list.add("iPhone");
                    list.add("Windows XP");
                    return list;
                }

    // Adapter Class            
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

                List<String> arrayList;      
                List<String> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
                LayoutInflater inflater;

                public MyAdapter(Context context, List<String> arrayList) {
                    this.arrayList = arrayList;
                    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return arrayList.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return arrayList.get(position);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                private class ViewHolder {
                    TextView textView;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    ViewHolder holder = null;

                    if (convertView == null) {

                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                                .findViewById(R.id.textview);
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
                    } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                    }
                    holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
                    return convertView;
                }

                @Override
                public Filter getFilter() {
                    Filter filter = new Filter() {

                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        @Override
                        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                            arrayList = (List<String>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                            List<String> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<String>();

                            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                                mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                            }

                            /********
                             * 
                             *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                             *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                             *
                             ********/
                            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                                // set the Original result to return  
                                results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                                results.values = mOriginalValues;
                            } else {
                                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                                for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                                    String data = mOriginalValues.get(i);
                                    if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                        FilteredArrList.add(data);
                                    }
                                }
                                // set the Filtered result to return
                                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                                results.values = FilteredArrList;
                            }
                            return results;
                        }
                    };
                    return filter;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Lalit Poptani i have tried your code its not working for me ,i need your could you please let me know if you can help

Comment: @Lalit Poptani i had filter same way but i have one problem that list.add("Linux");list.add("Windows7");list.add("Linux");list.add("Windows7"); meance i had repeted data when i search Linux i found two data when i click on second data and going to find id from another listview in which i had compare value so it will give me first list view id but i want other so can you tell me something about this.

Comment: dude are you there@Lalit Poptani,i have some doubt how to modify my code according to your answer

Comment: @Lalit Poptani I want to Filter 4 ArrayLists. Please Help any tutorial. I want to filter latitude and longitude values Arraylisy also. and Have to handle OnItemCLik LIstener Accordingliy. Thanks

Comment: It is preferably to use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` method instead of construction `if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {`

Comment: what are the mOriginalValues stand for here?

Comment: mOriginalValues stands for ArrayList that stores original values of Array

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `getFilter()` in your custom adapter.

Comment: i have implemented getFilter(),bt it dont give accurate result.Can u refer the code written in adapter and help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

While Lalit's solution works perfectly, you can implement the SearchView in ActionBar which make your UI fancier. You can get SearchView in your activity as mentioned below -

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

    mListView = getListView();
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    setupSearchView(searchView);

    menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Search Text")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void setupSearchView(SearchView mSearchView) {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Text");
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.setFilterText(newText);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ComponentInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PaintFlagsDrawFilter;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.PaintDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Displays a list of all activities which can be performed
 * for a given intent. Launches when clicked.
 *
 */
public abstract class LauncherActivity extends ListActivity {
    Intent mIntent;
    PackageManager mPackageManager;
    IconResizer mIconResizer;

    /**
     * An item in the list
     */
    public static class ListItem {
        public ResolveInfo resolveInfo;
        public CharSequence label;
        public Drawable icon;
        public String packageName;
        public String className;
        public Bundle extras;

        ListItem(PackageManager pm, ResolveInfo resolveInfo, IconResizer resizer) {
            this.resolveInfo = resolveInfo;
            label = resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm);
            ComponentInfo ci = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
            if (ci == null) ci = resolveInfo.serviceInfo;
            if (label == null && ci != null) {
                label = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
            }

            if (resizer != null) {
                icon = resizer.createIconThumbnail(resolveInfo.loadIcon(pm));
            }
            packageName = ci.applicationInfo.packageName;
            className = ci.name;
        }

        public ListItem() {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter which shows the set of activities that can be performed for a given intent.
     */
    private class ActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
        private final Object lock = new Object();
        private ArrayList<ListItem> mOriginalValues;

        protected final IconResizer mIconResizer;
        protected final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        protected List<ListItem> mActivitiesList;

        private Filter mFilter;

        public ActivityAdapter(IconResizer resizer) {
            mIconResizer = resizer;
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) LauncherActivity.this.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mActivitiesList = makeListItems();
        }

        public Intent intentForPosition(int position) {
            if (mActivitiesList == null) {
                return null;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(mIntent);
            ListItem item = mActivitiesList.get(position);
            intent.setClassName(item.packageName, item.className);
            if (item.extras != null) {
                intent.putExtras(item.extras);
            }
            return intent;
        }

        public ListItem itemForPosition(int position) {
            if (mActivitiesList == null) {
                return null;
            }

            return mActivitiesList.get(position);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mActivitiesList != null ? mActivitiesList.size() : 0;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(
                        com.android.internal.R.layout.activity_list_item_2, parent, false);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
            }
            bindView(view, mActivitiesList.get(position));
            return view;
        }

        private void bindView(View view, ListItem item) {
            TextView text = (TextView) view;
            text.setText(item.label);
            if (item.icon == null) {
                item.icon = mIconResizer.createIconThumbnail(
                        item.resolveInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));
            }
            text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.icon, null, null, null);
        }

        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (mFilter == null) {
                mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
            }
            return mFilter;
        }

        /**
         * An array filters constrains the content of the array adapter with a prefix. Each
         * item that does not start with the supplied prefix is removed from the list.
         */
        private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<ListItem>(mActivitiesList);
                    }
                }

                if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        ArrayList<ListItem> list = new ArrayList(mOriginalValues);
                        results.values = list;
                        results.count = list.size();
                    }
                } else {
                    final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                    ArrayList<ListItem> values = mOriginalValues;
                    int count = values.size();

                    ArrayList<ListItem> newValues = new ArrayList(count);

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        ListItem item = values.get(i);

                        String[] words = item.label.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ");
                        int wordCount = words.length;

                        for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                            final String word = words[k];

                            if (word.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                                newValues.add(item);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    results.values = newValues;
                    results.count = newValues.size();
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                //noinspection unchecked
                mActivitiesList = (List<ListItem>) results.values;
                if (results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Utility class to resize icons to match default icon size.  
     */
    public class IconResizer {
        // Code is borrowed from com.android.launcher.Utilities. 
        private int mIconWidth = -1;
        private int mIconHeight = -1;

        private final Rect mOldBounds = new Rect();
        private Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();

        public IconResizer() {
            mCanvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(Paint.DITHER_FLAG,
                    Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

            final Resources resources = LauncherActivity.this.getResources();
            mIconWidth = mIconHeight = (int) resources.getDimension(
                    android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a Drawable representing the thumbnail of the specified Drawable.
         * The size of the thumbnail is defined by the dimension
         * android.R.dimen.launcher_application_icon_size.
         *
         * This method is not thread-safe and should be invoked on the UI thread only.
         *
         * @param icon The icon to get a thumbnail of.
         *
         * @return A thumbnail for the specified icon or the icon itself if the
         *         thumbnail could not be created. 
         */
        public Drawable createIconThumbnail(Drawable icon) {
            int width = mIconWidth;
            int height = mIconHeight;

            final int iconWidth = icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            final int iconHeight = icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

            if (icon instanceof PaintDrawable) {
                PaintDrawable painter = (PaintDrawable) icon;
                painter.setIntrinsicWidth(width);
                painter.setIntrinsicHeight(height);
            }

            if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                if (width < iconWidth || height < iconHeight) {
                    final float ratio = (float) iconWidth / iconHeight;

                    if (iconWidth > iconHeight) {
                        height = (int) (width / ratio);
                    } else if (iconHeight > iconWidth) {
                        width = (int) (height * ratio);
                    }

                    final Bitmap.Config c = icon.getOpacity() != PixelFormat.OPAQUE ?
                                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    final Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIconWidth, mIconHeight, c);
                    final Canvas canvas = mCanvas;
                    canvas.setBitmap(thumb);
                    // Copy the old bounds to restore them later
                    // If we were to do oldBounds = icon.getBounds(),
                    // the call to setBounds() that follows would
                    // change the same instance and we would lose the
                    // old bounds
                    mOldBounds.set(icon.getBounds());
                    final int x = (mIconWidth - width) / 2;
                    final int y = (mIconHeight - height) / 2;
                    icon.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
                    icon.draw(canvas);
                    icon.setBounds(mOldBounds);
                    icon = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumb);
                } else if (iconWidth < width && iconHeight < height) {
                    final Bitmap.Config c = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    final Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIconWidth, mIconHeight, c);
                    final Canvas canvas = mCanvas;
                    canvas.setBitmap(thumb);
                    mOldBounds.set(icon.getBounds());
                    final int x = (width - iconWidth) / 2;
                    final int y = (height - iconHeight) / 2;
                    icon.setBounds(x, y, x + iconWidth, y + iconHeight);
                    icon.draw(canvas);
                    icon.setBounds(mOldBounds);
                    icon = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumb);
                }
            }

            return icon;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        mPackageManager = getPackageManager();

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        onSetContentView();

        mIconResizer = new IconResizer();

        mIntent = new Intent(getTargetIntent());
        mIntent.setComponent(null);
        mAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(mIconResizer);

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }

    /**
     * Override to call setContentView() with your own content view to
     * customize the list layout.
     */
    protected void onSetContentView() {
        setContentView(com.android.internal.R.layout.activity_list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = intentForPosition(position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Return the actual Intent for a specific position in our
     * {@link android.widget.ListView}.
     * @param position The item whose Intent to return
     */
    protected Intent intentForPosition(int position) {
        ActivityAdapter adapter = (ActivityAdapter) mAdapter;
        return adapter.intentForPosition(position);
    }

    /**
     * Return the {@link ListItem} for a specific position in our
     * {@link android.widget.ListView}.
     * @param position The item to return
     */
    protected ListItem itemForPosition(int position) {
        ActivityAdapter adapter = (ActivityAdapter) mAdapter;
        return adapter.itemForPosition(position);
    }

    /**
     * Get the base intent to use when running
     * {@link PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(Intent, int)}.
     */
    protected Intent getTargetIntent() {
        return new Intent();
    }

    /**
     * Perform query on package manager for list items.  The default
     * implementation queries for activities.
     */
    protected List<ResolveInfo> onQueryPackageManager(Intent queryIntent) {
        return mPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(queryIntent, /* no flags */ 0);
    }

    /**
     * Perform the query to determine which results to show and return a list of them.
     */
    public List<ListItem> makeListItems() {
        // Load all matching activities and sort correctly
        List<ResolveInfo> list = onQueryPackageManager(mIntent);
        Collections.sort(list, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(mPackageManager));

        ArrayList<ListItem> result = new ArrayList(list.size());
        int listSize = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
            ResolveInfo resolveInfo = list.get(i);
            result.add(new ListItem(mPackageManager, resolveInfo, null));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```