# Searching a listview with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

My app has a twoline **ListView** with a **custom adapter**. I want to filter the listview contents with the input to a EditText. How is it possible?

```
lv.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(),recordObjects));
//recordObjects is an ArrayList of objects
```

Comment: [Here is an answer for the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result/8678198#8678198)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set `TextWatcher to your EditText` and

and then filter your data using dynamic array...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`addTextChangedListener`](http://goo.gl/IvCYv) method to add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`. Then in your implementation of `onTextChanged`, add or remove the items from your `ListView`'s adapter as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you wanted?

```
ListView lv = getListView();
            /* Gets a ListView */
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            /* sorts the listview */
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    result.getheadlines());
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            /*
             * gets the lisadapter from the XML and sets it equal to
             * whatever result is
             */
```