# How list view Filter works in android

Tags: android, list

i m new in android .and i need to create filter for json array .i need to knew the work flow of custome getfilter .means what it changes .
1. it change adopter or what is happning inside after **calling**

```
getfilter.filter(s)
```

i need to knew so i can create my custom filter.

and one more thing i didn't find the reasonable full tutorial on list filtering and list custom filtering if any one can find it or any one can make then it will really help me and other beginners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering in ListView works with implementing `Filterable` to your Adapter class and overriding `getFilter()` method which further overrides `publishResults()` and `performFiltering()`. You can just check my answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678198/726863) with a complete demo code that how it works.

Comment: this is the part i knew but what i didnt knew what is changing in performfiltering() did it change the adopter and after changing it it called getview again for filtered itmes

Comment: @nomee.tec It would be better that you just have a look at my answer and read the comments to get better idea about how it works.