# how to implement filter on listview

Tags: android, filter, android-listview

I had a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result) before asking a question here. But that thread contains example of simple string array whereas in my case I am using `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` so I am bit confused at the moment.

I have a multiple selection `listview` in my android activity. I am using the `listview` to display the list of contacts so that the user can select multiple phone numbers at a time. But now I want to add the search functionality for the same purpose. What I want to do is place one `EditText` at the top and whatever character users types in that `EditText`, I want the `ListView` to be filled with filtered data based on users input. I have a `CustomAdapter` which extends `BaseAdapter` and a POJO class named `Contact` which I am using to `GET` & `SET` contact details.

**MYCUSTOMADAPTER.JAVA**

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mAdapData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

public MyCustomAdapter(Context mContext) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
    ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
        if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(i);
            final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
            mTempArry.add(numbr);
        }
    }
    return mTempArry;
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.mAdapData.size();
}

public void addItem(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    Map<String, String> NameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
    NameNumber.put("Name", paramString1);
    NameNumber.put("Phone", paramString2);
    this.mAdapData.add(NameNumber);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
    return (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) this.mAdapData.get(paramInt);
}

public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
    return paramInt;
}

public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {

    if (paramView == null) {
        paramView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiplecontactview, null);
    }

    TextView txtName = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
    TextView txtNumber = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
    CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    mCheckBox.setTag(paramInt);
    mCheckBox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(paramInt));
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
    txtName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    txtNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(paramInt);
        final String name = map.get("Name").toString();
        final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
        txtName.setText(name);
        txtNumber.setText(numbr);
    }
    return paramView;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
};
}
```

**CONTACT CLASS**

```
public class Contact {

int _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;

public Contact() {

}

public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number) {
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

public Contact(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public Contact(String name, String _phone_number) {
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

public int getID() {
    return this._id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this._name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this._name = name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return this._phone_number;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number) {
    this._phone_number = phone_number;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you to be able to do that, you need to implement a [Textwatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        /*clear previous contents of list*/
                     adapter.clear();
                    /*add new contents according to the filter*/
                   String filter=arg0.getText().toString();
                   if (filter == null
                            || Pattern
                                    .compile(Pattern.quote(filter),
                                            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                                    .matcher(adapter.getItem(...)).find()
                            || filter.equals("")) {
                        adapter.addItem(...);
                    }
    }

};
```

Then set that filterTextWatcher to your editext:

```
searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

Hope that helps! :)