# Android Filter ListView Using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, filter, baseadapter

We need to implement the code of filter list view in this example.  We are using a 2 classes : `Car.java` (contains the Object Car), Class `CarAdapter` extends the `BaseAdapter` Class.
Below is some of codes:

**Car.java**

```
public class Car {

public String title;
public int car_id;

public Car(String title,int car_id) {
    this.title = title;
    this.car_id = car_id;
}

}
```

**CarAdapter.java**

```
public class CarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Car> mCarList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CarAdapter(List<Car> list, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    mCarList = list;
    mInflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCarList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mCarList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewItem item;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.prototype, null);
        item = new ViewItem();


        item.CarTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TextViewPrototype);

        convertView.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Car curCar = mCarList.get(position);

    item.CarTitle.setText(curCar.title);    

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewItem {
    TextView CarTitle;
}

}
```

**CarActivity.java**

```
 public class ActivityCar extends Activity {

private List<Car> mCarList;
private EditText et;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.car);
    // Obtain a reference to the product catalog
    mCarList = CarHelper.getCar(getResources());
    // Create the list
    ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_car);
    listViewCatalog.setAdapter(newCarAdapter(mCarList,getLayoutInflater)));

}   
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question is.... how to filter the data??

Comment: Exactly. How to filter the data in the listview(containing car.title)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to make the listview filterable:

1. In `CarAdapter.java` implement the [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface. Take a look at similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8678198/645762).
2. In `CarActivity.java` set Listview adapter to be filterable.
   `listViewCatalog.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`
3. If you had used `android.widget.SearchView` then implement [SearchView.OnQueryTextListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html) or if you used `EditText` then implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) interface.