# Filtering listview data of simple_list_item_2 items using searchview and arrayadapter

Tags: fragment, filtering, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem, searchview

I'm writing an android application (Min API 14) which consists of 3 tabs that hold a fragment each.
One of the fragments holds a list view (with a list view item defined as simple_list_item_2) and a search view. Now, I'm trying to filter the data in the list view by a room's name (Room is my model)

```
    protected SearchView searchView;
    protected ListView view;
    protected List<Room> rooms;
    protected ArrayAdapter<Room> roomAdapter;        
    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), container, false);
        view = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(getListViewId());
        searchView = (SearchView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rooms_search_view);
        view.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   ....
        roomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Room>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, rooms){     

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row;
                if(convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater =                             
                       (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getApplicationContext().
                            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = (View)inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
                }else{
                    row = (View)convertView;
                }
                Room data = rooms.get(position);
                TextView v = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                v.setText(data.getName());
                v = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
                v.setText(data.getPhone());
                return row;
            }


      };
      view.setAdapter(roomAdapter);
  ....    
      return rootView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
      roomAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
      return true;
  }
```

The problem is that the search results are in no way relevant to the input entered in the search view. When I replace *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2* with *android.R.layout.simple_list_item* everything work as expected.

I also read that overriding the toString() method in my model(Room) would solve such a problem,
but that didn't work either.

Any help figuring out how to filter by title(android.R.id.text1) would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, After I couldn't find any solution with the 'standard' android adapters, I ended up writing a custom adapter that extends *BaseAdapter* and implements *Filterable*.
You can find some hints in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result) if you encounter the same problem.