# how to filter the custom listview in android

Tags: android, listview, search

i am using one custom list view for fetching data from json parsing,
now i have one edittext, which is used to search the items listed in listview, how can i achieve the seach functionality. any help would be appreciated.

```
ListView_res_name_main_cetegires = (ListView)     findViewById(R.id.list_costome_list_main_cetegories);
Custome_res_main_cetegories customAdapter_res_name_main_cetegiores;                             
if(language.equalsIgnoreCase("English"))
{
   customAdapter_res_name_main_cetegiores = new Custome_res_main_cetegories(getApplicationContext(), array_str_name_eng,language);
}else
{

   customAdapter_res_name_main_cetegiores = new Custome_res_main_cetegories(getApplicationContext(), array_str_name_arab,language);
}

ListView_res_name_main_cetegires.setAdapter(customAdapter_res_name_main_cetegiores );
```

Comment: How do you populate your listview?

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result?lq=1

Comment: also, if you load data from resources 


don't do array_str_name_eng,language


just use resources with postfixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EditText to search then you have to write your own filter method..here is an example [Custom ListView Search](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/). If you can't get it then let me know I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks @Ketan, this example will help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should not filter ListView, but adapter,

```
Adapter adapter = new CustomAdapter();
ListView_res_name_main_cetegires.setAdapter(adapter);
```

on data loaded:

```
adapter.setData(your data);
```

on search :

```
adapter.filter(searchQuery)
```

in setData, filter methods do not forget to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to implement search functionality in a list view. First add an edit text in which you will enter the text to be searched in the list view. Below is the rest of the code:

```
**main.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:hint="Search">
</EditText>

<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for the activity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewSearchExample extends Activity
{
private ListView lv;
private EditText et;
private String listview_array[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE",
"SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT", "NINE", "TEN" };
private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));

et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
                                                                // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
}
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
int start, int count, int after)
{
// Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
int start, int before, int count)
{
textlength = et.getText().length();
array_sort.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < listview_array.length; i++)
{
if (textlength <= listview_array[i].length())
{
if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
(String)
listview_array[i].subSequence(0,
textlength)))
{
                                                                                                                array_sort.add(listview_array[i]);
                                                                                                }
                                                                                }
                                                                }
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
(ListViewSearchExample.this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_sort));
}
});
}
```

Hope this one is helped.