# how can i get the current position of listView after it getFilter()?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, baseadapter

**My question asked before : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018155/filter-in-android-is-taking-the-wrong-position) .If you do not understand me.**
I have a listView with baseAdapter class on my app and my problem is: 
User typing on the editText some letter in it and after the listView return him the all "Names" with this letter(addTextChangedListener) . now, 
Evrything work fine but when the adapter set the "new list" with the result ,I Can't get the current Data from the current position from the list. Explain the theory :

- my list is :
- posistion 0. Name: A Phone: 111111
- posistion 1. Name: B Phone: 222222
- posistion 2. Name: C Phone: 333333

and when i type the letter "C" my list show this result:
 position 0 : Name C: Phone: 111111 (phone is"111111" because that target to position "0")

but in "0" position i have the Phone value of  A .

Here my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Person> contactList;
    CustomContact adapterContact;

    //Temp
    ArrayList<String> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> groupListName = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Person> tempList;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);

        txTempName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTempName);



        edNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edPhoneOrName);
        edMass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edMass);

        timepicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePickerMain);
        timepicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePickerMain);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContact);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);





        edNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    refreshContact();
                } else {
                    MainActivity.this.adapterContact.getFilter().filter(s);

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }
        });

}

    public void refreshContact(){
    DbHandContact hand = new DbHandContact(this);
    hand.open();
    contactList  = hand.getAll();
    hand.close();
    Collections.sort(contactList,contactSort); 
    adapterContact = new CustomContact(this, contactList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapterContact);

    tempList = (ArrayList<Person>) contactList.clone();

}

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if(true){


                String currentCellPhone = tempList.get(position).getCellPhone();
                String name = tempList.get(position).getName();

                groupList.add(currentCellPhone);
                groupListName.add(name);

                Toast.makeText(this, currentCellPhone+" "+name, 2000).show();

                for (int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
                    txTempName.setText(groupList.get(i));
                }

            }
        }
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class CustomContact extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Activity context;
    ArrayList<Person> list;


    protected ArrayList<String> temporarylist;

    public CustomContact(Activity context, ArrayList<Person> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_contact, parent,false);

        ImageView imgPerson,ImgDial;
        TextView txName,txLastName,txCellnum,HomeNum;

        txName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_name);
        txLastName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_lastName);
        txCellnum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_cellNum);


        imgPerson = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_picture);


        txName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        txLastName.setText(list.get(position).getLastName());
        txCellnum.setText(list.get(position).getCellPhone());


        return row;
    }

     @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    list = (ArrayList<Person>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<Person> FilteredList = new ArrayList<Person>();
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                        // No filter implemented we return all the list
                        results.values = list;
                        results.count = list.size();

                    } else {

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            String data = list.get(i).getName();


                            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {

                                FilteredList.add(list.get(i));
                            }


                        }
                        results.values = FilteredList;
                        results.count = FilteredList.size();

                    }

                    return results;
                }
            };

            return filter;
        }




}
```

Comment: so do you just want current position of the listview item?

Comment: The simple position  i know how to get. the problem is after i create the TempList

Comment: This solution solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926517/listview-custom-filter-gives-wrong-item-selected-when-filtered-android

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Filter part code only change:

```
@Override public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    list = (ArrayList<Person>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<Person> FilteredList = new ArrayList<Person>();
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                        // No filter implemented we return all the list
                        results.values = list;
                        results.count = list.size();

                    } else {

            constraint = constraint.toString();
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            String data = list.get(i).getName();


            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {



                                FilteredList.add(list.get(i));



                        }
                        results.values = FilteredList;
                        results.count = FilteredList.size();

                    }

                    return results;
                }
            };

            return filter;
        }
```

and editext code here:

search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // Call back the Adapter with current character to Filter
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Matt check this line and compare your 
code constraint = constraint.toString();
and also this line
if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {

Comment: i am trying to sort the list by EditText using filter in adapter.
Filter is processing well but the position of listview click is always constant.
i.e. ListView is getting filter but after selection of item its taking the same position in the list view.

Comment: It's nor working i think you do not understand the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by one of two cases that you can use application class and when it updated in adapter update it in the application class and then you can access from the activity/fragment and whenever you want

and the second option to use sharedpreferences to save it and the same for retrieving it at any place also