# Search filter on listview returns wrong results on item click

Tags: android, android-filterable

I have done my fair share of research and found three cases related to my problem.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018155/filter-in-android-is-taking-the-wrong-position)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562556/filtered-listview-onitemclick-returns-item-at-original-position)

[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926517/listview-custom-filter-gives-wrong-item-selected-when-filtered-android)

I am not saying that my case is unique or anything,it is jus that i cannot make their answers work for me with my cord.

**PROBLEM:** I have a `listview` getting filtered by an `edit text` on top.However when i click on the item searched i get the result of another image being selected.Text works fine but images is the problem.

**For example:** list has rows with images A,B,C,D

On searching C you get the result filtered as C.But clicking on it results on showing image from A.It is like the position does not change for the images but uses the original `ArrayList` adapter position.

Any help will be appreciated.

My adapter:

```js
public class SearchListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    List<Model> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Model> modelItems;
    private int mDefaultImageId;

    public SearchListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Model> modelItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.modelItems = modelItems;
        mStringFilterList = modelItems;
    }


    public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
        mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modelItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return modelItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);

        Model m = modelItems.get(position);

        // thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);
        thumbNail.setTag(position);
        // title
        title.setText(m.getTitle());

        // amount
        rating.setText(String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

        // description
        String genreStr = "";
        for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
            genreStr += str + ", ";
        }
        genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
                genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
        genre.setText(genreStr);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Model> filterList = new ArrayList<Model>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++)
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getTitle().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {


                        Model m = new Model(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getTitle(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getThumbnailUrl(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getRating(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getGenre());

                        filterList.add(m);
                    }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            modelItems = (List<Model>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

```js
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                        .getText().toString();
                bitmap = ((Model) modelList.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();
                String rate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating))
                        .getText().toString();
                String genres = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre))
                        .getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, Details.class);
                intent.putExtra(Title, name);
                intent.putExtra("images", bitmap);
                intent.putExtra(Rate, rate);
                intent.putExtra(Genre, genres);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

OnItemclickListener:

Comment: You have `private List<Model> modelItems` in your adapter, but use `modelList.get(position)` in the listener, why is that? What is `modelList`? It's inner list of adapter which is updated, and it's where you should take your item from

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the code

```
String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
bitmap = ((Model) modelList.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();
String rate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rating)).getText().toString();
String genres = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre)).getText().toString();
```

to

```
Model model=(Model)adapter.getItem(position);
```

It will get the model on which position you clicked and pass this model as Serialized or what you want to do.

Hope this will solve problem.

Comment: and dont forget to add-> @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return modelItems.get(location);
    }  in adapter

Answer (score 6):

use

```
 Model model = (Model) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

to retrieve the item from your dataset, and use this reference to fill up the `Intent` object. After you filter the items in your Adapter, you are overriding, with `modelItems = (List<Model>) results.values;` the current reference of `modelItems`.

Edit

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             Model model = (Model) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, Details.class);
            intent.putExtra(Title, model.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("images", model.getThumbnailUrl());
            intent.putExtra(Rate, String.valueOf(model.getRating()));
            intent.putExtra(Genre, model.getGenre());

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay I am trying to figure out where the first code you gave me goes to..sorry,newbie much.

Comment: If I remove the other lines how will I display the items in the other activity?

Comment: The onitemclick is on my activity

Comment: Could you update the question and show how did you the changes I suggested you?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are filtering your adapter, but then getting an item from your original unfiltered list. You should get the item directly from your adapter. Add the following method to your BaseAdapter:

```
public Model getItemAtPosition(int position)
{
    return model.get(position);
}
```

and call that from your `OnItemClickListener` implementation:

`bitmap = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).getThumbnailUrl();`

Comment: This is my preferred solution, very clean and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `onClickListener` returns `position=0`,when `onClick`,because in your filtered `ListView` it has only one item `C` `index=0` where zeroth index refers to `image A`,Thats why its displaying `A image`
Refer this for your Solution :[Get Original Index from Filtered list view](https://web.archive.org/web/20170604105525/http://www.survivingwithandroid.com:80/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)

Comment: I checked out this example.. Very simple to understand. But I did not get to see where he achieves what I am not able to accomplish.However I am grateful for your suggestion +1.

Comment: Link is  broken now