# update position listview after search

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have a listview of 30 items. I can search in the listview successfully but when i clicked those what i searched, I dont get the informations about this item. The searched item was normally in the 21th of the Json. After i searched it, it came to upper rows in the listview. When I’ve done itemclick, it gives result of 0th item. How can i fix it?

```
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
}

private async void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     int i;
     i = e.Position;???
}
```

Comment: You cannot fix it, its the default behavior of search functionality you implemented, use a Hash-map or some key value pair to identify.

Comment: It seems like you are filtering your adapter, but then getting an item from your original unfiltered list. You should get the item directly from your adapter. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850070/3111083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are searching among the list item.

**Solution.**

- Use two list (Permanent and temporary)
- Both list contain the same data set in the beginning but the temporary
  list can change while you search.No changes will be made to permanent list ever
- Pass the temporary list to you adapter and keep the permanent list
  intact.
- Add addTextChangedListener() on search text view
- While you search using any keyword. add those items in your
  temporary list that matches your search criteria.
- The temporary list contain only those item that are being searched.
- Notify the adapter
- When you clear your search field clear the temporary list to and add
  all the item from permanent list to temporary.
- Notify the adapter

**Example use case**

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        String searchWord = charSequence.toString();
        if (mPermanentList.size() > 0) {
            if (searchWord.length() > 0) {
                mTemporaryList.clear();
                for (i = 0; i < mPermanentList.size(); i++) {
                    if (mPermanentList.get(i).getName().contains(searchWord)) {
                        mTemporaryList.add(mPermanentList.get(i));

                    }
                    mFilesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                mTemporaryList.clear();
                mTemporaryList.addAll(mPermanentList);
                mFilesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi follow below link and those helps you to solve your problem.

https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308

Note : And handling click within adapter (getView()) not in activity.

Hope it helps and if it working for you then please closed this questions.

Comment: @menontheChessboard welcome and my answer solved your problem?