# added filter to customised listview but its not working

Tags: android, listview

How can I add filter to the customised listview like the one below? I tried adding a method but could not get the arraylist and adapter working together .I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LauncherActivity.ListItem;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private final Activity activity;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private Filter mFilter;

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    //////
    private ArrayList<ListItem> mOriginalValues;
    List<ListItem> mActivitiesList;


    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }


    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<ListItem>(mActivitiesList);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    ArrayList<ListItem> list = new ArrayList(mOriginalValues);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<ListItem> values = mOriginalValues;
                int count = values.size();

                ArrayList<ListItem> newValues = new ArrayList(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    ListItem item = values.get(i);

                    String[] words = item.label.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ");
                    int wordCount = words.length;

                    for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                        final String word = words[k];

                        if (word.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                            newValues.add(item);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            mActivitiesList = (List<ListItem>) results.values;
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;



    EditText ed;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678163/list-filter-custom-adapter-dont-give-result

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I have editted the code above with the changes you mentioned but its not working.Please check it out really appreciate youyr time.